# Azure App Service Can't find flask app in nested folder. Even with GUnicorn

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service, gunicorn

I have a flask app which I'm able to run locally no problem, the issue is when I try to run it in Azure, it seems the app.py can't be found since I'm deploying with GitHub. My file tree looks something like below, and Azure starts in the /Chatbot folder. I need to get into /Chatbot_Application/Chatbot to access app.py

```
Chatbot 
├─── .vs
├───Chatbot_Application
│   └───Chatbot
│       ├───chatbot_backend
|       ├───app.py
|   ├─gunicorn.conf.py
```

If I run the Azure app like this I get no code output, IF I adjust the start up configuration to this

```
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --chdir /Chatbot_Application.Chatbot app:app
```

I get an error "can't chdir to 'Chatbot_Application.Chatbot'" no matter what format I put.
I'm thinking of going the wsgi.py route but I don't think I'll get any luck because it won't be able to import the app.py modules.

Comment: So, the solution was using this format for the startup command. 'gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 Chatbot_Application.Chatbot.app:app' This will help Azure recognize the app.py, keep in mind the module within my app.py is called app so that's why it's app:app. Now to solve the issue of cannot find module 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the solution was using this format for the startup command.

```
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 Chatbot_Application.Chatbot.app:app
```

This will help Azure recognize the app.py, keep in mind the module within my app.py is called app so that's why it's app:app. You'll have to solve the issue 'cannot find module'

Comment: Thanks a LOT man! This fixed the problem for me as well. Please mark this answer as the solution so more people can find this fix